# Prevent Size property from being serialized when it's equal to default value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create my own class from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`

```cs
public class MyButton : Button
{

    public MyButton() : base()
    {
        Size = new Size(100, 200);
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "100, 200")]
    public new Size Size { get => base.Size; set => base.Size = value; }
}
```

I have a problem with **Designer.cs** behavior - default value is not working properly.

I expect, that when `MyButton` is added to form, it has Size of 100x200, but it is not set through **Designer.cs**, so when in `MyButton` constructor I change Size to 200x200 (also for DefaultValue) all `MyButton` get new size. Of course, when I change the size in Design Mode it should then be added to **Designer.cs** and not affected by later changes in `MyButton` class.

Although, in current configuration Size is always added to **Designer.cs**.

I tried different approaches (with Invalidate() or DesignerSerializationVisibility) but with no luck.

I want to Stop `Size` from being serialized when it is equal to `DefaultValue`. For example when it is dropped from toolbox to form - it is instantly serialized in designer, while I don't want that - only serialize when I change the size.

Comment: Is your goal stopping the default size from getting serialized?

Comment: Stopping Size being serialized when it is equal to DefaultValue. For example when it is dropped from toolbox to form - it is instantly serialized in designer, while I don't want that - only serialize when I change the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the `ControlDesigner` replaces `Size` property in the `PreFilterProperties` with a custom property descriptor which its `ShouldSerializeValue` always returns `true`. It means the `Size` property will be always serialized unless you decorate it with designer serialization visibility attribute having hidden as value.

You can change the behavior by restoring the original property descriptor:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(MyButtonDesigner))]
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override Size DefaultSize
    {
        get { return new Size(100, 100); }
    }

    //Optional, just to enable Reset context menu item
    void ResetSize()
    {
        Size = DefaultSize;
    }
}
public class MyButtonDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    protected override void PreFilterProperties(IDictionary properties)
    {
        var s = properties["Size"];
        base.PreFilterProperties(properties);
        properties["Size"] = s;
    }
}
```